# android push notification shows blank content

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications

I am showing alerts using google cloud messaging in android.it is working in some devices and emulator but do not work all device , like Samsunng Galaxy Grand and some of my emulators, it just displays the Icon and title of the notification while the message is blank.

```
mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, MyActivity.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Siom Alert")//TITLE CAN BE TSKEN FROM HERE
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(mes))
            .setContentText(mes);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: r u getting any error

Comment: Check your key for Message at your side. Is it the same as server sidE??

Comment: no i am not getting any error. the only problem is that in some devices the notification title, icon, message is displayed perfectly. But the same notification will show just icon, title, but message will be blank.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
 private void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)   context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, message, when);         
        String title = "New POC Alert";         
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, null);
        // set intent so it does not start a new activity
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        // Play default notification sound
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

        // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
    }
```

//Mainfest permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="vibrate" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one.

```
// Put the message into a notification and post it.
// MainActivity is the activity which you wish to load. Setting setWhen() with 0 will not publish time.

private void sendNotification(String msg) {
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.your_app_icon)
                    .setContentTitle(getResources().getText(R.string.your_title))
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                            .bigText(msg))
                    .setWhen(0).setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                    .setContentText(msg)
                    .setAutoCancel(true);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
}
```

I hope you have the needed permissions.
Reference: [GCM Reference](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html#manifest)

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply but what i notices is that if i give static text in ContentText then it appears as it should. The problem arises only when i am using a variable in then it doesnt show up

Comment: Did you try to debug? I hope you are parsing it properly. I don't think providing static message works and passing as a parameter does not.

Answer (score -1):

try like this may help you

```
mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, MyActivity.class), 0);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
      NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Siom Alert")//TITLE CAN BE TSKEN FROM HERE
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(mes))
                .setContentText(mes);

    } else {
          //code for simple notification
    }
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply but what i notices is that if i give static text in ContentText then it appears as it should. The problem arises only when i am using a variable in then it doesnt show up